# GitHub Desktop: Commits lost/deleted

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

We're currently having a revamp of our website, therefore we created a new branch `revamp` from `main`.

Everybody does their changes in the `revamp` branch.

Now following scenario happened:

- Monday: My coworker committed "commit A".
- Tuesday: I committed "commit 1", "commit 2" and "commit 3".
- Wednesday: My coworker wanted to commit "commit B". However, when trying to push his changes, GitHub Desktop notified him, that there were changes that he hadn't pulled yet (my commits 1, 2 and 3 from tuesday)
- Naturally, he fetched my commits and then hit "push". GitHub Desktop created two commits:

  1. "commit B"
  2. "Merge branch 'revamp' of https://github.com/company-name/project-name into revamp"
- Thursday: When pulling the new changes, my changes 1, 2 and 3 were gone from the codebase. They were still in the GitHub Desktop History. However when inspecting his commits in the History, "commit B" only showed some unrelated changes and "Merge branch 'revamp'..." shows `No files in commit`. I could not see, where the code was removed.

It took me a while to figure out, that I can only see the deletion when hitting the button "Compare changes" on https://github.com on the "Merge branch 'revamp' into revamp" commit.
(The URL looks somewhat like https://github.com/company-name/project-name/compare/18511cb70baa1b55de4b9b84366a82e8d26eb9a2...9a619b35d10a62d73b2cbf4e0ae9f71e87008822, I think it's git diff, but not too sure.)

I tried:

1. I cannot "revert changes in commit" on the commit named "Merge branch revamp into revamp", GitHub Desktop says `There are no changes to commit` (remember, it says `No files in commit`).
2. I created a new branch from my last commit "commit 3" until we figured out the solution and I will do his last "commit B" manually, since it was a one-liner.

Is this related to GitHub Desktop? I'm not too familiar with the git commands, so maybe GitHub Desktop used the wrong approach of merging, or simply scrambled up stuff(?)

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Cheers, Boris

Edit: Here's how it looks on https://github.com when using the "Compare changes":
[image]

Comment: Did you actually investigate whether the project state contains your changes when you check out commit "Merge branch revamp ... into revamp"? To me, all sounds like things worked out just fine; it's just your misinterpretation of what happened when GitHub says "No files in commit" for a merge commit.

Comment: When I check out the commit "Merge branch revamp ... into revamp" (which is the latest commit anyway), my changes are not in the source code anymore, if I understood you correctly.

Comment: Then you have to talk to your coworker how they went about to create the merge commit. One possible reason is that there were merge conflicts and they resolved them incorrectly.

Comment: I will talk to him again. Thanks for your input! This happened before and I wanted to rule out a problem in how we're using GitHub Desktop. But looks like an user error then.

Comment: What exactly is the question. Do you want to know how to fix this problem if it happens again, or do you want to know why it happened?

Comment: "Everybody does their changes in the revamp branch" Are you really saying you have multiple people committing directly on the same branch???

Comment: No, @matt, clearly everyone has a local version of "the revamp branch", and "the revamp branch" that is talked about is the remote one.

Comment: @j6t That would be a Yes, not a No. If everyone is committing directly to their own local copy of "the revamp branch" and pushing to the same "the revamp branch", that is arguably a wrong use of Git and is exactly the cause of the issues here. None of this could have happened if everyone worked on their own feature branch, pushed the feature branch, and merged at GitHub using a pull request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everybody does their changes in the revamp branch

Well, that's the problem. You have multiple people making their own commits on, and pushing, one and the same branch. That is a recipe for trouble, and trouble is exactly what you're getting.

Instead, everybody should do their "changes" (i.e. make commits) only an their own individually created local branch, and should push that branch to GitHub where the branch can be merged using a pull request. That way:

(1) The issue "when trying to push his changes, GitHub Desktop notified him, that there were changes that he hadn't pulled yet" will never happen (unless someone rewrites history within their own branch, and in that case pushing with force is fine).

(2) No one's commits will stomp on anyone else's commits; all the commits will be merged to, and thus interleaved on, the ultimate target branch `revamp`.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will read into working with pull requests. I guess we were just lucky until now because we're a small team.

Comment: You don't have to use pull requests. But even a team of 2 people should use different branches plus merge to some single target branch that neither ever commits to directly. Two people committing directly to the same branch is a very bad idea, and kind of throws away one of the main points of Git.

Comment: Thanks Matt. The only this that still bugs me is how a file could have been affected that my coworker didn't even work on. Do you think it's possible GitHub Desktop did try to push too fast before the pull was finished and my coworker still had the old version? It's not a file anything is listening to (e.g. a preprocessor or autoformatter). Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with GitHub Desktop. It seems more like you just don't understand what Git is, what a branch is, what a merge is, that sort of thing. I think it would help for you to read my introduction: https://www.biteinteractive.com/picturing-git-conceptions-and-misconceptions/ I cannot give a more detailed explanation of what happened here because (1) your description of the steps is inadequate, and (2) I cannot see your GitHub repository. But it sounds to me like what happened is normal and correct given the architecture you were using (multiple people working on one branch).

Comment: I will gladly read into it, can't thank you enough.